# Converter JSON em 2 string em php

Tags: php, mysql, json

Boas.
Eu tenho um ficheiro json que queria converter em 2 string em php para depois escrever na base de dados; o meu json de momento vem assim:

```
    [
  [
    1455628560,
    2340
  ],
  [
    1455628620,
    2340
  ],
]
```

O meu problema é seleccionar a data UNIX TimeStamp e colocar numa string e colocar os valores de baixo noutra string.

Até ao momento estou a trabalhar com o seguinte codigo;

```
<?php

$sensorid='###';
$token='###';

$interval='###';      #{hour, day, month, year, night}
$unit='###';     #{watt, kwhperyear, eurperyear, audperyear, lpermin, lperday, m3peryear}
$resolution='###';      # {minute, 15min, hour, day, week, month, year, decade, night}


$db_user = "###";
$db_pass = "###";
$db_host = "###";
$db_name = "###";
$table   = "###";




class Flukso {
        private $sensorid, $token, $interval, $unit, $resolution;
        private $url='https://api.flukso.net/sensor/';

        public function __construct($u_sensorid, $u_token, $u_interval, $u_unit, $u_resolution) {
                $this->sensorid = $u_sensorid;
                $this->token = $u_token;
                if (empty($u_interval)) {
                        $this->interval = 'hour';
                } else {
                        $this->interval = $u_interval;
                }      
                if (empty($u_unit)) {
                        $this->unit = 'watt';
                } else {
                        $this->unit = $u_unit;
                }
                $this->resolution = $u_resolution;
                $this->getdata();
        }

        private function getdata() {
        <a href="http://www.flukso.net/content/jsonrest-api-released<br />
        " title="http://www.flukso.net/content/jsonrest-api-released<br />
        ">http://www.flukso.net/content/jsonrest-api-released<br /></a>          
                $header=array();
                $header[]="Accept: application/json";
                $header[]="X-Version: 1.0";
                $header[]='X-Token: '.$this->token;

                $request=$this->url.$this->sensorid.'?interval='.$this->interval.'&unit='.$this->unit.'&resolution='.$this->resolution;

                $ch=curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$request);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
                $this->data=curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);

        }
        public function __toString() {
                return $this->data;
        }

}



$fluksodata = new Flukso($sensorid, $token, $interval, $unit, $resolution);

$fluksodata=json_decode($fluksodata);



$link = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass)
       or die ("Error ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."Failed to connect to MySQL.\n<b>A fatal MySQL error occured</b>.\nQuery: " . $query . "\nError: (" . mysql_errno($link) . ") " . mysql_error($link). " Affected rows is ".mysql_affected_rows($link));
mysql_select_db ($db_name)
       or die ("Error ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."Failed to connect to the database ".$db_name.".\n<b>A fatal MySQL error occured</b>.\nQuery: " . $query . "\nError: (" . mysql_errno($link) . ") " . mysql_error($link). " Affected rows is ".mysql_affected_rows($link));


foreach($fluksodata as $value){


        if ( "$value[1]" != "nan" )
        {

                $corrected_ts = $value[0] - 3660;
                $formatdatetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $corrected_ts);
                $year = date('Y', $corrected_ts);

                $corrected_value = $value[1];

                $query = "insert ignore into $table (ts, value) values ('$formatdatetime', $corrected_value)";
                $result = mysql_query ($query)
                        or die ("Error ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."Failed to insert ".$table." record.\nA fatal MySQL error occured.\nQuery: " . $query . "\nError: (" . mysql_errno($link) . ") " . mysql_error($link). " Affected rows is ".mysql_affected_rows($link));

        }      
}



mysql_close($link);

?>
```

De momento a tabela no mysql fica assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alterei o codigo para funcionar e colocar os dados corretamente na mysql falta apenas o codigo para não copiar valores se esses ja existiram na base de bases

Answer (score 0):

A maneira mais facil de se tratar json em PHP é com 
json_decode() e json_encode();

```
<?php
$jsonStr = "[
  [
    1455628560,
    2340
  ],
  [
    1455628620,
    2340
  ]
]";


$json = json_decode($jsonStr);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($json);
echo $json[0][0];
echo "\n";
echo $json[1][0];
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: Certo mas como é que eu divido os dois valores em strings? Eu de momento so consigo meter tudo junto na tabela e eu queria criar 2 colunas uma com "1455628560" e ou com "2340" e por ai a fora

Comment: Criar 2 colunas seria inserir no banco de dados ou exibir no navegador?

Comment: colocar nas duas colunas do banco de dados eu vou colocar um print da tabela como ela fica depois de colocar os dados no mysql